# "Access Point Name settings are not available for this user" on unrooted 1st Gen Moto G. Help, please?

Tags: motorola-moto-g, apn

I recently did a factory reset of 1st Gen Moto G, after which the mobile data stopped working . In trying to fix the problem, I noticed I couldn't change the APN settings, and when I go to that option in the settings menu I get the message "Access Point Name settings are not available for this user". Does anyone have any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: It sounds like you're on the Guest account, or something.  What do you see in Settings -> Users?  What version of Android do you have?

Comment: @MatthewRead I'm quite sure I'm not on the guest account. In "Users" I see "You (Jay)" and below that "Guest". My android version is 5.1. Thanks.